# Storing directory names in list and displaying

Tags: arrays, powershell, scope

I am trying to do a mass import of tables into SQL. To do this I need to open a main directory and then cycle through those sub-directories to execute the actual files. I cannot seem to store these sub-directory names in a list.

Here is my code:

```
$path = "E:\Dictionary_SQL_Commands\";
$i = 0;

#I would like to dynamically allocate this space as I do not know the length
$global:contents = new-object object[] 10;

foreach ($item in $path){
    $global:contents[$i] = $local:item.name;
    $i++;
}
```

`$contents` gets created and I can view it using `gci variable:` but the output is `{$null,$null,...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a "list". This is Powershell.

```
# Get all File items in the given path recursively #
Get-ChildItem -Path:$path -Recurse -File | 
# Process each one as it's available #
    Foreach-Object { 
        # Get the contents of each file #
        $Contents = Get-Content $_; 
        # do other stuff with $Contents here #
    }
```

This is the Powershell [pipeline](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847902.aspx)

Comment: "You don't need a "list". This is Powershell."                                            Ahhhh... I get it. thanks! @Eris